# Difference between rows based on condition python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, row, difference, between

I am using python dataframe, but can use something else it is easier..

I need to calculate the difference between date between transactions in minutes.

I need to calculate the difference of time in minutes between each row, BUT it should calculate difference where hash is equal to previous row spent*transaction*hash.  In example would be difference like column H:

```
hash    spent_transaction_hash  block_timestamp    Difference
a   b                     2021-09-11 04:14:32+00:00      0
b   c                     2021-09-09 01:53:22+00:00     C2-C3
c   d                      2021-09-09 00:47:42+00:00    C3-C4
d   e                      2021-09-09 00:47:42+00:00    C4-C5
e   f                      2021-09-08 23:20:37+00:00    C5-C6
e   g                      2021-09-08 23:20:37+00:00    C5-C7
f   h                      2021-09-08 03:13:17+00:00    C6-C8
g   j                       2021-09-07 09:07:27+00:00   C7-C9
h   k                       2021-09-07 22:56:08+00:00   C8-C10
j   l                       2021-09-07 07:03:46+00:00   C9-C11
k   m                      2021-09-07 06:06:28+00:00    C10-C12
```

How can I achieve something like that?

I used this formula

```
block_time_min_diff= df["block_timestamp"].diff().apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).fillna(0).astype('int64')
```

but noticed it is wrong..
UPDATED:

Using your suggestion, it checks with previous row and then calculates difference, but if the value is not in previous row but 3 rows up?
Example would be:

Where we have hashes  e and f so the code calculates correct, but next row is e and g and code should calculate  2021-09-09 00:47:42+00:00  -  2021-09-08 23:20:37+00:00, so should be the same as e and f row, but it comes 0.

also later:
g   j row should be 2021-09-08 23:20:37+00:00  -  2021-09-07 09:07:27+00:00|
but now it calculates  2021-09-08 03:13:17+00:00  - 2021-09-07 09:07:27+00:00.

How can I change a code a bit?

Comment: Please don't post sample data as image

Comment: sorry, changed it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the difference in transaction times of two successive rows if they have the same hash value for the hash column and the previous `spent_transaction_hash`.

First we set `successive_transactions_indicator` to locate which rows have the same hash than the row before. For this we want to set the value to `1` if the previous row has the same hash, else `0`.

```py
successive_transactions_indicator = (
  (df.hash.shift() == df.spent_transaction_hash) 
  .apply(lambda diff_hash: 0 if diff_hash else 1)
)
```

Then, we can multiply this new Series with your column of time differences. In one hand we will have the difference of times computed, on the other hand we only keep those which have the same hash as the previous row, else its value would be 0.

```py
successive_transactions_times = (
  df.block_timestamp.diff().div(np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).fillna(0)
  * successive_transactions_indicator
)
```

I replaced your `apply` with a `div`, it's better to avoid using `apply` when you can do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated main question a bit, this code almost solved my problem